# How do you set html / body tag attributes in Meteor.js?

Tags: meteor

I need to set attributes on the html tag or alternatively the body tag of the document in a Meteor.js application.

Specifically I want to have `<html dir="rtl">` or `<body dir="rtl">`..

Trying the latter, I receive the console message:

```
While building the application:
client/views/layout/layout.html:7: Attributes on <body> not supported

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

So how do you do this?

Answer (score 19):

You have to inject them on start-up in your client-side Javascript:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
   $('html').attr('dir', 'rtl');
});
```

**UPDATE**

Note that you can now set attributes in-line for body tags, and they'll be concatenated by Meteor in the same way as the contents of the body tag:

```
<body data-atttribute="foobar"></body>
```

You can have multiple different body tags, and they'll get combined, so the above will just add a single attribute to your existing body, rather than replacing it.

To the best of my knowledge, HTML tag attributes still need to be set via Javascript.

Comment: @richsliv is there non js solution?

Comment: Meteor is a javascript framework, but you could use coffeeScript.

Answer (score 9):

Attributes for HTML tag can be set on `startup` by using `WebApp.addHtmlAttributeHook` function. Here is an example:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    WebApp.addHtmlAttributeHook(function() {
        return {
            "dir": "rtl"
        }
    })
});
```

Make sure you call this on server, not client.

Comment: It can also be done with helmet: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1790#issuecomment-334099975

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else stumbles upon this to realise the above solutions don't work anymore, here's what worked for me with Meteor 2.13:

```js
Meteor.startup(() => {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
});
```

Found it here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor-feature-requests/issues/322