# Correct way to use Meteor with Modernizr

Tags: meteor, modernizr

#### What is the correct way to use Meteor with Modernizr?

1. I'd like to use [modernizr-meteor](https://github.com/ckir/modernizr-meteor), but don't know how it works or how to customize it. Do I simple get a custom build off modernizr, and then merge the js file with the latests `yepnope.js`
2. Since Modernizr needs a `no-js` class in the html, I can simply [add the class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21109313/2317532) in on startup.

**in `/lib/startup.js`**

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
   $('html').attr('class', 'no-js');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to use 3rd party libraries with Meteor is to install them from Meteor's package repository, Atmosphere.

A [search for Modernizr reveals](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=modernizr) two packages. As a rule, packages with `mrt` in the organization name (the part before `:`) were automatically migrated, and generally out of date. They should be flagged.

The other package looks like a decent ([not ideal](https://github.com/cwaring/meteor-modernizr/issues/3)) candidate, so you'd run:

```
meteor add cwaring:modernizr
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Especially the note about `mrt`. There are often more than one package (or I think people call it a 'wrapper') for a certain library, so now knowing about `mrt` helps me narrow down the choices.

Comment: @dayuloli: you're welcome. I've started an effort to consolidate wrappers (and hopefully eliminate them). [Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Packaging_existing_Libraries) / [Discussion](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-community-discussions/issues/14) / [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-idz8UPtDM).

Comment: Thank you for your work in the community, I will definitely have a read over it during lunch!